# Trouble with deep routes on a single-page app on Firebase hosting

Tags: reactjs, firebase, webpack, react-router, firebase-hosting

(Updated below with a little more info)

We have a react-based single-page web app that lives on Firebase Hosting. We've been using hash-based routing up to this point (e.g. `mysite.com/#/path/to/content`). We introduced React Router, which allows us to have prettier URLs (e.g. `mysite.com/path/to/content`), but now the app doesn't load when we navigate directly to a deep route. Details below:

Using React Router required us to use URL Rewriting in Firebase Hosting. The directions are pretty straightforward--it seems like all you need to do is this:

```
"rewrites": [ 
    {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
    }
]
```

...inside the `firebase.json` file. In fact, our complete `firebase.json` file is as follows:

```
{
"firebase": "",
"public": "dist",
"rules": "rules.json",
"ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/*.map",
    "**/node_modules/**"
],
"rewrites": [ 
    {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
    }
]
}
```

Nothing too complicated there (we're doing `firebase deploy -f` in our build script, if you're wondering why the `firebase` argument is empty). The linked-to `rules.json` file is even simpler:

```
{
   "rules":{
   ".write":"true",
   ".read":"true"
 }
}
```

When I load the app by going to the base URL and start navigating around, everything is fine. If I go directly to a route at one level deep (e.g. `mysite.com/path`), that works too.

HOWEVER

If I go directly to a route at a deep level, or even to a top-level route with a trailing slash (e.g. `mysite.com/path/` or `mysite.com/path/to/content`), then the app doesn't load.

Specifically, what happens is the `index.html` page loads, and then browser goes to load our webpack-created bundle.js file that is referenced in `index.html`, but what Firebase Hosting returns for that JS file is *the content of the index.html file*. So then, predictably, what we see in the browser console is this error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

...on line 1 of the "bundle file". If I view the content of the bundle file in Chrome's dev tools, line 1 of the bundle file is literally this:

`<!doctype html>`

...which is then followed by the rest of the HTML from the `index.html` file.

It seems like what's going on is the Firebase URL rewrite rule is saying "oh, you're trying to reference a JS file--I see I'm supposed to return the content of `index.html` for everything, so here you go". But that can't be the case all the time, or the site would never work under any circumstances. So why does it work if I start at the site root, but breaks if I paste in a deep URL to the app? I have zero idea.

If it helps, here's how my `index.html` file references the bundle file:

```
<script src="bundle.ce843ef7a2ae68e9e319.js"></script></body>
```

So it seems like a problem with Firebase hosting, but I could also see that maybe I don't understand React Router at some level, and so I've somehow screwed things up with the client-side code in such a way that it's forcing the server to return the wrong thing.

Here's me hoping it's some stupid configuration thing we're missing. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

UPDATE: I stripped down our app so that it only returns "hello, world", which bypasses all of the React-based stuff, including React Router, and the problem persists, so I no longer think this has anything to do with React-Router, though I suppose there's still a small chance this could have something to do with React.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I heard back from Firebase Hosting. Apparently, the referenced bundle.js file in our index file needed a slash in front of it, to make it an absolute path. So this:

```
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

...instead of this:

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

In case anybody else makes this same silly mistake, I hope this is useful.

Comment: Thank you! I was having the same problem, keep in mind this will also affect the CSS files references, you need the / on those as well.

Comment: @hairbo: Thanks B, never thought I'd see an old co-worker on StackOverflow, much less get help from one! This answer helped me on a side-project.

Comment: Nice! Glad to hear it, Ezra! Hope all is well.

Comment: Brilliant stuff, such an oversight on my part and a great explanation here. Thanks. Because the OP talks about react, I'd like to mention that webpack production configuration needed a `output: {publicPath: '/'}` for me.

Comment: This is unbelievable! I'm here for 3 hours looking in every config item and it was a slash. I'm kind of nervous and happy at the same time

Comment: It has not solved for me. My webpack-dev-server is giving correct behavior. But using root relative path did not solve the same probelm for me.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same behavior but the problem was unrelated to `bundle.js`.

My `rewrites` section of `firebase.json` looked like this:

```
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "index.html"
      }
    ]
```

and I resolved the problem by using the **root relative path** instead of the **relative path** for `index.html`. (Thanks Ashu!)

```
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

**[tl;dr]**

> This answer is **only for educational purposes** and in-depth insight to
>   the problem statement and its solution. For copy/paste purposes see
>   [this answer provided by @hairbo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35511625/4836759). It is the short version and
>   answers the question simply and nicely

Every link to resources like images, css, js can be referenced to in 3 ways:

**1) Absolute Path**

```
<script src="http://app-url.com/bundle.js"></script>
```

This is absolute path and resource will be loaded from the specified path without pre-processing the path provided.

**2) Relative Path**

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

This is relative path and it refers to the resource file as if it is located in current working directory. That is  when you are on `app-url.com/lvl-1` the relative path becomes `app-url.com/bundle.js` which provides no problems because that is actually the path to resource.

**Problem**

But upon going another level deep, i.e. `app-url.com/lvl-1/lvl-2`, current working level becomes `app-url.com/lvl-1/` and the relative path is treated as `app-url.com/lvl-1/bundle.js` but that is not actually the path to resource. Hence the index.html file mis-behaves because it can't load the required files.

**3) Root Relative Path**

```
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

Adding a slash (/) before the relative path makes it root relative path. In this case all non-absolute paths are treated as paths rooted at the current domain. That is, in this case the path to resource `/bundle.js` is treated as `app-url.com/bundle.js` even if current working level of url is `app-url/lvl-1/lvl-2/lvl-3/...`

> **Solution** Do not use ~relative paths~. Either use absolute paths or root relative paths in all files. This way every path will be treated
>   as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and I fixed adding rewrite rules to my firebase.json file.

here is how my firebase.json file looks.

```
    {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "webApp/build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {    
    "source": "functions"
  }
}
```

sorry for my english, i still learning.