# React deep/nested router not working when hosted on firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, webpack, react-router, firebase-hosting

I have checked stackoverflow related to my this problem but none addresses it.

I am using nested routes for my reactJS app which is working fine on my local `webpack` server but not working on `firebase` hosting. Strangely it works till `/admin/dashboard` route but any further routes does not work i.e. `/admin/list-bayaans` or `/admin/listBayaans` it shows error [**no matching route found**] in browser console.

**Routes.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, IndexRoute, Link} from 'react-router';

import Layout from './components/layout';
import Homepage from './components/homepage';
import Bayaans from './components/bayaanspage';
import Readquran from './components/readquran';
import Duas from './components/duaspage';
import Events from './components/eventspage';
import Contactpage from './components/contact';

import AdminLayout from './components/admin/adminLayout';   // admin section (using same theme with little style variation)
import LoginPg from './components/admin/loginPage';
import Dashboard from './components/admin/dashboard';
import AdminBayaansPg from './components/admin/adminBayaansPage';
import AdminDuasPg from './components/admin/adminDuasPage';
import AdminEventsPg from './components/admin/adminEventsPage';

// we are defining 'home' route explicitly as an patch for now. So if user is on any innner page and he clicks the HOME menu then '/home' will render as '/' does not work and does nto return to the index page. Need to see it though.

export default (
            <div>
                 <Route path="/" component={Layout} >
                    <IndexRoute component={Homepage} />
                    <Route path="home" component={Homepage} />
                    <Route path="bayaans" component={Bayaans} />
                    <Route path="read-quran" component={Readquran} />
                    <Route path="duas" component={Duas} />
                    <Route path="events" component={Events} />
                    <Route path="contact" component={Contactpage} />
                 </Route>

                 <Route path="/admin" component={AdminLayout} >
                    <IndexRoute component={LoginPg} />
                    <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                    <Route path="list-bayaans" component={AdminBayaansPg} />
                    <Route path="list-duas" component={AdminDuasPg} />
                    <Route path="list-events" component={AdminEventsPg} />
                 </Route>
             </div>
);
```

**Problem:2**
When I try to deploy again on firebase by changing routes using `firebase deploy` command and when I check in browser the routes stay same. *(Yes I was rebundling my code and then was deploying. Also I was only making small text changes in one route just to debug as I mentioned in very start of my question. i.e. `/list-bayaans` vs `/listBayaans`*

**Note:** I have checked this link also but it is not relevant and already have what is mentioned in this link: [Trouble with deep routes on a single-page app on Firebase hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35468826/trouble-with-deep-routes-on-a-single-page-app-on-firebase-hosting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now. Basically `firebase` take couple of minutes to load up new deployment changes (sometimes). In my case it took around 15 minutes.